# ¿Como aplicar estilo focus a un componente fuera de un div?

Tags: css, reactjs

Estoy realizando un formulario de **log in** para el cual estoy utilizando **Ant design** y `css` propio.

El problema que tengo es que no le puedo aplicar el estilo a un icono que esta fuera del contenedor del input.

---

### css que quiero aplicar

```
#input:focus + i {
  color: #ccced3;
}
```

### Funciona

Forma en la que funciona el estilo, pero no puedo utilizarlo de esa forma debido a como esta hecho el `Form` de [Ant design](https://ant.design/components/form/?theme=dark#components-form-demo-complex-form-control)

```
<Form.Item 
    name='password'
    className="input-container"
>
    <Input
        id="input"
        type="password"
        placeholder="password"
    />
    <i className="icon">
        <LockOutlined />
    </i>
</Form.Item>
```

### No funciona

```
<Form.Item className="input-container">
    <Form.Item name='email'>
        <Input
            id="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="email"
        />
    </Form.Item>
    <i className="icon">
        <UserOutlined />
    </i>
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se trata simplemente del selector que estás utilizando.

```
#input:focus + i {
  color: #ccced3;
}
```

Busca el elemento que está **exactamente después (y en el mismo nivel de jerarquía)** que el elemento `#input:focus`

En tu ejemplo, el elemento `i` está un nivel por encima en la jerarquía, por lo que no puedes seleccionarlo con una expresión que parta de #input.

¿Puedes añadir una clase al elemento `<Form.Item name="email">` o a `<Form.Item className="input-container">`?

En tal caso pordías intentar actuar sobre el elemento `i` sin alterar tu estructura haciendo:

```
# HTML

<Form.Item className="input-container">
    <Form.Item class="MY_CLASS" name='email'>
        <Input
            id="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="email"
        />
    </Form.Item>
    <i className="icon">
        <UserOutlined />
    </i>
</Form.Item>
```

```
# CSS

.MY_CLASS:focus-within + i {
  color: #ccced3;
}
```

Comment: ok en este caso si puede agregar una clase al elemento  `<Form.Item className="input-container">` como sería el `css`?

Comment: Sería tal y como pongo en la respuesta, substituyendo MY_CLASS por el nombre que le des a esa clase.

Comment: si eso lo entiendo pero me parece que si lo pongo a ese nivel, dicha clase no funcionaria correctamente, por lo que menciona de que busca el siguiente elemento que se encuentra al mismo nivel y `<Form.Item className="input-container">` se encuentra un nivel mas arriba.